# calculate cosine between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate cosine between two vectors **a** and **b** where

$a=2x-y,\quad b=2x+y, \quad \left\| x \right\| =\left\| y \right\| =2,\quad \left(x \mid y \right) =1$.

ANSWER:

$$\begin{align}
\cos\theta & =  \frac { \left( { 2x-y } \mid { 2x+y } \right)  }{ \left\| 2x-y \right\| \left\| 2x+y \right\|  } \\
& = \frac { 4{ \left\| x \right\|  }^{ 2 }-{ \left\| y \right\|  }^{ 2 } }{ \sqrt { 4{ \left\| x \right\|  }^{ 2 }+{ \left\| y \right\|  }^{ 2 }-4\left( x \mid y \right)  } \sqrt { 4{ \left\| x \right\|  }^{ 2 }+{ \left\| y \right\|  }^{ 2 }+4\left( x \mid y \right)  }  } \\
& = \frac { 6 }{ 4\cdot 2\sqrt { 6 }  } \frac { \sqrt { 6 }  }{ 8 }
\end{align}$$

Is it ok? Could you explain me what happens in by calculating the norm. Why not just sum of squares but also this $-4(x \mid y)$?

Should I think about **a** and **b** as vectors which contain vectors as its elements?

Comment: ABOUT LaTeX formatting. I noticed that i newest question list it is not rendering properly. What way should I place LaTeX code, so that it renders everywehre on math stackexchange properly? Thanks for reply.

Comment: $a=2x-y$, ok, but what are $x$ and $y$? Which vector space is that?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a basic tutorial on LaTeX and MathJax.

Comment: @Integral they're some other vectors with $\|x\|=\|y\|=2$ and $(x|y)=1$

Comment: @andi please contact me. I would like you to undelete your question about the differential equation, because before you deleted it I had an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question about "Why not just sum of squares but also this −4(x∣y)?", that's the exact expression for the norm of a vector.
$$\left \| 2x-y\right \|  = \sqrt{\left( 2x-y \right| 2x-y )} = \sqrt{4\left (x|x \right )-2\left( x|y\right)-2\left( x|y\right)+\left( y|y\right)} = \sqrt{4 \left \| x\right \|^2 - 4\left( x|y\right) + \left \|y \right \|^2}
$$
Same for $\left \| 2x+y\right \| = \sqrt{\left ( 2x+y|2x+y\right )} = \sqrt{4 \left \| x\right\|^2 + 4 \left( x|y\right )+\left \| y\right \|^2}$

### Update

If I understood your request correctly, you want to see the difference between inner(dot) product of vectors components of which are numbers, and vectors that are linear combination of other vectors. So the answer is - there isn't any difference.

Let's say $\mathbf a = (a_1, a_2)$, $\mathbf b = (b_1, b_2)$ then you can say $\mathbf a = a_1 \mathbf i + a_2 \mathbf j, \mathbf b = b_1 \mathbf i + b_2 \mathbf j$, where $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$ are unit vectors on $x$ and $y$ axes correspondingly. So
$$
\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b = \left(a_1 \mathbf i + a_2 \mathbf j\right ) \cdot \left (b_1 \mathbf i + b_2 \mathbf j \right ) = a_1b_1 (\mathbf i \cdot \mathbf i) + a_1b_2 (\mathbf i \cdot \mathbf j) + a_2b_1 (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf i) + a_2b_2 (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf j)
$$
It's just turned out that $(\mathbf i \cdot \mathbf i) = (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf j) = 1$, and $(\mathbf i \cdot \mathbf j) = (\mathbf j \cdot \mathbf i) = 0$, due to the orthonormality of $\mathbf i$ and $\mathbf j$, so
$$
\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf b = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2
$$
and 
$$
\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf a = a_1^2 + a_2^2
$$

Comment: Would like to Vote Up if I can. I was to much used to calculate dot product on elements being certain number, so thaht was probabyl source of confusion. Thanks for answare. It would be nice, if you could generalize your answer by pointing difference in calculating dot product on certain numbers and expressions with variables. Or point to some good explanation on the web.

Comment: @andi I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

If the vectors involved have real entries, then your symbolic calculation looks OK, but the concrete answer is wrong. It should be $\frac{12}{\sqrt{16\times24}}=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{6}}$.

**Edit:** I overlooked the question on $-4(x|y)$. For real vectors, we have $\|v\|^2=(v|v)$ and $(u,v)=(v|u)$, so
$$\|2x-y\|^2=(2x-y \mid 2x-y)=(2x|2x)-(y|2x)-(2x|y)+(y|y)=4\|x\|^2-4(x|y)+\|y\|^2.$$

Comment: Should i think about a and b as vectors which contain vectors as its elements?

Comment: No, $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are ordinary vectors that contains numeric entries, but I am not sure those entries are real numbers or complex numbers. Since $\langle x,y\rangle$ is a real number in this case, whether the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ will make no difference, but it doesn't hurt to be more specific.

Comment: I stay in Real. If a,b and x,y are vectors, then a and b are vectors which contain vectors, isn't it?

Comment: @andi Let's say $x=(2,0)^T$ and $y=(1/2, \sqrt{15}/2)$. Then $x$ and $y$ are real vectors containing real numbers as their entries. You may verify that $\|x\|=\|y\|=2$ and $(x|y)=1$. Now $a=2x-y=(7/8, -\sqrt{15}/2)$ and $b=2x+y=(9/2, \sqrt{15}/2)$ are also vectors that contain *real numbers* as entries. They don't "contain vectors".

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question about $-4(x|y)$, even if $x$ and $y$ are complex you have $(2x-y|2x+y)=4(x|x)-2(y|x)+2(x|y)-(y|y)$.  Given that $(x|y)$ is real, $(y|x)+(x|y)^*=(x|y)$ so the cross terms add out.

Comment: I think, you're answering to the wrong question :)

Comment: @andi:  I thought you were wondering why there isn't a $-4(x|y)$ in the numerator.  I think Kaster has the answer to the question you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think $x$ and $y$ are entries of $a$? $a$ and $b$ are still the usual vectors with entries of *real numbers*. The equations $a = 2x - y$ doesn't mean $x$ and $y$ are entries of $a$. It means you multiply $2$ with $x$ (scalar multiplication) and add this vector to $y$ (vector addition) to get another vector $a$.

For exmaple, you could have $(2, 3, 4) = 2(1, 1, 1) + (0, 1, 2)$ where $a = (2, 3, 4), x = (1, 1, 1), y = (0, 1, 2)$.

Also, this is the reason you are wondering why there is the $-4(x|y)$ term. As I explained $x$ and $y$ are not entries of $a$, so to find the inner product, you don't just add their squares. You have to do a bit of algebra using the rules for inner products as shown by Kaster.

Hope this clear up any confusion.